# Spring HATEOS : Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.hateoas.config.HypermediaRestTemplateConfigurer' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate, spring-hateoas

I am trying to build a simple REST client using the [Spring HATEOS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#client.rest-template) library.

I get the following exception when trying to register my `RestTemplate` with a `HypermediaRestTemplateConfigurer`

```
**************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method hypermediaRestTemplateCustomizer in com.rest.client.config.RestClientConfiguraiton required a bean of type 'org.springframework.hateoas.config.HypermediaRestTemplateConfigurer' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.hateoas.config.HypermediaRestTemplateConfigurer' in your configuration.
```

**Question :**  **How do I create a `HypermediaRestTemplateConfigurer` instance myself? I assumed this class would have been autoconfigured by spring boot as per the example documentation?**

**My code :**

**Main class**

```
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class RestClientApplication {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(RestClientApplication .class, args);
        }
    
        @Bean
        public CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception {
            return args -> {
                String taskExecutionResources = restTemplate.getForObject(
                        "http://mydataflow-server.myhost.net/tasks/executions?name=task1225",
                        String.class);
                System.out.println(taskExecutionResources);
            };
        }
    
    }
```

**Configuration class**

```
import java.time.Duration;

import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.hateoas.config.HypermediaRestTemplateConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

    @Configuration
    public class RestClientConfiguraiton {
    
        @Bean
        public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
            return builder.setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(5)).build();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public RestTemplateCustomizer hypermediaRestTemplateCustomizer(HypermediaRestTemplateConfigurer configurer) {
            return restTemplate -> {
                configurer.registerHypermediaTypes(restTemplate);
            };
        }
    
    }
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>rest-client</name>
    <description>Rest client for SCDF server</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Try to remove the tomcat exclusion from the pom.xml

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That does not seem to be co-related to this question in anyway. I only excluded tomcat because I don't need it. keeping Tomcat dependencies results in the same outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use `@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = HypermediaType.HAL)` above my `@Configuration` annotated class. (i.e for `RestClientConfiguraiton` class show in my question)

Luckily there was a mention of this in [HypermediaAutoConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/hateoas/HypermediaAutoConfiguration.html) Java Docs :

> Auto-configuration for Spring HATEOAS's @EnableHypermediaSupport.